# Why is IsConst emitted twice in char * const a

Tags: c++-cli, clr, cil, ildasm

I've disassmebled the following C++/CLI code in ildasm:

```
Managed(char * const a)
{

}
```

and the disassembled IL looks like this:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void  .ctor(int8 modopt([mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsSignUnspecifiedByte)* modopt([mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsConst) modopt([mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsConst) a) cil managed
```

Removing some insignificant parts:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor(int8* modopt(IsConst) modopt(IsConst) a) cil managed
```

So while there is only one `const` in the original code, it is emitted twice in the IL. Why is that so?

Comment: FYI, if I create a method with just one `modopt(IsConst)`, it seems to behave the same as a method with two of them, when referenced from C++/CLI.